# Two questions on the permutohedron

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, permutations, polyhedra, convex-hulls

The $n$-dimensional permutohedron $P_n$ is the polytope given by the convex hull of all the possible permutations of the vector $(1,2,\dots,n+1)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. So it has $(n+1)!$ vertexes.

I would like to ask if there is a formula for the the number of integer points of $P_n$ and whether it is known that $P_n$ is a very ample polytope for any $n\geq 1$.

For instance, $P_2$ is an hexagon in $\mathbb{R}^3$ contained in the plane $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 6$. It has $7$ integer points and it is very ample.

Comment: Do you agree with my edit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number of integer points in $P_n$ is the number of forests on $[n]$; see Section 3 of Stanley's [Decompositions of rational convex polytopes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/40.pdf). In fact you can see there a simple description of its entire Ehrhart polynomial in terms of forests. (See also Section 9.3 of Beck and Robins's book [Computing the continuous discretely](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/ccd.pdf).)

The toric variety corresponding to the permutohedron is also very well-studied, and is often called the "permutohedral variety," but I don't know off the top of my head an answer to your question on ampleness. I would take a look at the book by Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky, which is a seminal source for a lot of this.

**EDIT**: Okay, I looked up the definition of very ample polytope. A lattice polytope $\mathcal{P}$ is *very ample* if for every $N \gg 0$, and $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}\cap N\mathcal{P}$, there are $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_N\in \mathbb{Z}\cap \mathcal{P}$ such that $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a}_1+\cdots+\mathbf{a}_N$. In fact, the (standard) permutohedron has a stronger property than this. It has the *Integer Decomposition Property (IDP)* which says that for every $N\geq 1$, and $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}\cap N\mathcal{P}$, there are $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_N\in \mathbb{Z}\cap \mathcal{P}$ such that $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a}_1+\cdots+\mathbf{a}_N$ (this property is also sometimes called *normal*, in the context of algebraic geometry, I think). The reason the permutohedron is IDP is because any lattice zonotope is IDP: every zonotope has a tiling by half-open parallelepipeds, and these parallelepipeds are easily seen to be IDP; and the permutohedron is a lattice zonotope- see Chapter 9 of the Beck-Robins book mentioned above.

As John Machacek linked to below, a recent paper of Higashitani and Ohsugi shows that in fact the class of Minkowski sums of unit simplices (which includes the regular permutohedra and many of the generalized permutohedra of Postnikov) have the IDP property.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is no closed formula then? Do you have any information on the very ampleness?

Comment: There's not going to be a product formula (like there is for the number of trees, Cayley's formula $n^{n-2}$, which is the normalized volume of the permutohedron), but you can certainly write a summation formula. I added a remark about the ampleness question- I don't know the answer to it.

Comment: The number of forests on $[n]$ is this OEIS sequence: http://oeis.org/A001858.

Comment: Also, compare this with the Birkhoff polytope, where the Ehrhart polynomial is still unknown

Comment: @JimRoss: See my update. The permutohedron is very ample, in fact, IDP, for a simple reason: it is a lattice zonotope and all lattice zonotopes are IDP.

Comment: See also this recent paper for IDP with Minkowski sums of simplicies: https://alco.centre-mersenne.org/item/ALCO_2020__3_4_831_0/

Comment: @ Sam Hopkins. Thank you very much. You helped me a lot! Many thanks to the others as well.

Comment: @JohnMachacek: Ah, that's a great reference, that proves much stronger results!

Comment: The link to Beck and Robins's book no longer works - but is seems to be [still available online](https://matthbeck.github.io/papers/ccd.pdf) on a new website: https://matthbeck.github.io/ccd.html and https://matthbeck.github.io/